# How to Identify if any item in a list exists as an element of another list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

Hopefully I can explain this well enough to get an answer.  What I am looking to do, preferably using linq, is to identify if an any item in a list of strings exists as an element in another list of objects. Here is a very generic example.

List 1 { "A","B","C","D"}

List 2 contains paired objects for instance 1,"A" and 2,"Z" and 3,"F".

What I would like to discover is if ANY of the strings in list 1 exist as the second element of list 2. AKA the first item in list 2 would be true because "A" is also in list 1.

Is there a way to accomplish this with linq?

Comment: Yes this is possible with LINQ, but if you want an exact answer then let us know what type of list List 2 is (or some of your code).

Comment: this is possible what have you actually tried on your own..?

Comment: list 2 is a list of objects where both elements are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming list2 is a collection of KeyValuePairs, like a Dictionary or Hashtable:

`list2.Any(i=>list1.Contains(i.Value))`

Although, based on your statement "the first item in list 2 would be true because "A" is also in list 1." it sounds like you want a "copy" of List2, with a boolean value for each as to whether they exist in List1. That would be:

`list2.Select(i=>new {item=i, exists=list1.Contains(i.Value)});`

Comment: This makes sense logically to me but (i._____) does not give me the option to add the string element from the list.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. This is absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start with list1:

```
bool result = list1.Any(elem => list2.Values.Contains(elem));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, you probably want a `GroupJoin`, which determines if the items in one list have one or more matches among a second list.

So, for your particular problem:

```
var letters = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

var pairs = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, Letter = "A" },
    new { Id = 2, Letter = "Z" },
    new { Id = 3, Letter = "F" }
};

var result = letters.GroupJoin(
    pairs, // join letters with pairs
    x => x, // use the whole letter as the matching key
    y => y.Letter, // use the Letter property as the matching key
    (x, ys) => new { Letter = x, Exists = ys.Any() }); // yield true if there are any matches, otherwise false
```